# How to make Todo MVC example work with AEM 6.0?

Tags: aem, sightly

After following the instructions to install : https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sightly-sample-todomvc/

When I go to: http://localhost:4502/content/todo.html

The page renders the following error:

```
TypeError: [object Object] is not a function, it is object
(/apps/todo/components/page/page.html#12)

Cannot serve request to /content/todo.html in /apps/todo/components/page/page.html
```

I can't find what is wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the adobe documentation:

While Sightly has been introduced as part of AEM 6.0, there is also a feature pack available that offers a backport of the implementation included in AEM 6.1 for use in AEM 6.0.
Sightly FP 1.1 - AEM 6.1 Sightly scripting engine for CQ 5.6.1 - 6.0

You may download and install the above feature pack from Package Share and replicate to the publish server. If you do use the feature pack offering this packport, please refer to the 6.1 version of the Sightly documentation.

Here's the link to download the feature pack:  https://www.adobeaemcloud.com/content/marketplace/marketplaceProxy.html?packagePath=/content/companies/public/adobe/packages/cq600/featurepack/cq-6.0.0-featurepack-6431